# How do we create OR Composite queries in datastore using gcloud ruby?

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using gcloud ruby gem and would like to issue a composite query (a = 1 and (b = 2 or c = 3)). I can only do single queries and possible AND queries using the following interface.

```
query = Gcloud::Datastore::Query.new
query.kind("Task").
  where("completed", "=", true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#Datastore_query_interface

> The Datastore currently only supports combining filters with the AND operator. However it's relatively straightforward to create your own OR query by issuing multiple queries and combining the results...

So your best option would be to run 2 queries separately:

- selecting records with a=1 and b=2
- selecting records with a=1 and c=3

And combining/deduplicating results manually.